# Linux Mint 21 cannot install some 32bit packages

Tags: linux-mint, 32-bit, packages

This is the result of running `sudo apt install wine32` on a Linux Mint 21 install, after installing the nvidia515 driver from the settings and enabling 32 bit support (`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`). I get the exact same error trying to install numerous other 32bit packages too. Aiming to install Steam and Lutris. Do you have an idea of what I can do?

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo apt install wine32
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
 dpkg : PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.2.2) but it is not installable
        PreDepends: libzstd1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installable
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 mintsources : Depends: python3-apt but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-requests but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mint-common (>= 2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.91 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-xapp-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: lsb-release but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
 util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
              PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Result of `dist-upgrade`:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Try `apt-get dist-upgrade` to remove/replace packages with changed dependencies.

Comment: @harrymc Updated with the result of the suggested command.

Comment: See this rather strong-arm [method](https://myotragusbalearicus.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/install-lotus-notes-9-on-ubuntu-13-04-64-bits/).